# Hi all I am looking for implementation examples of azure cognitive translator for websites . Please help us

Tags: azure, microsoft-translator

So as to provide multilingual support for one of our websites.

I could so only plain text conversion examples so it would really helpful if any one supports us

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use document translator for HTML.
[Code Samples](https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/DocumentTranslator?WT.mc_id=aiml-22492-ayyonet)

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/translator/document-translation/overview?WT.mc_id=aiml-22492-ayyonet) for more info.